# Is there a faster way to detect a game feature?

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a game. Five symbols will be displayed on the screen from 6 kinds of symbols at random.  If there are 3 or more of the same symbol adjacent on the screen, the player wins some money.

For example, if I have symbols `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F`.

`F` can substitute for any other kind of symbol (a wildcard).

So when `AAABC` or `AFABB`appear on screen, it means I win a `3-A` win.
If `AAFBB` appears on the screen, it means I win both a `3-A` and `3-B` win.

Now I have an array about what is displayed on the screen; I need find a **fast enough** way to detect the game result.

I've got this method now:

I give a code for each symbol: `A -> 1`, `B -> 2`, `C -> 3`, `D -> 4`, `E -> 5`, `F -> 0xF`.

Like I have an array: `{A,B,C,D,E}` I convert them to screen code: 0x12345.

Then I make a list of winning masks:

```
0x11111
0x22222
0x33333
0x44444
0x55555
0x11110
0x01111
0x22220
...
0x00111
0x01110
0x11100
```

I use the screen code, do `&` with each mask code, like `0x111f1 & 0x11111  == 0x11111`, then I know I have a `5-A` win.

Does any one have any other tricks to do this?

Comment: I don't think your masking system works.  If you have the code `ACEAA` and you apply the mask to check for 5 `A`s you get `0x13511 & 0x11111 == 0x11111` which says that you should get a `5-A` win, but this is not the case.

Comment: The whole solution space is not that big (6^5 = 7776), so just make a look up table and look it up...

Comment: Instead of A=1, B=2, etc... try to use A=0x01, B=0x02, C=0x04, D=0x08, E=0x10, F=0xFF.

Comment: @ilent2 So how to fix this ?

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira  If use you kind mask , means each symbol need at least 8 bit , however , it is worth to try.

Comment: @LidongGuo yes, but it is not very different from your approach. The main difference is that each symbol will be closely related to a bit, while yours is related to a fraction of a bit (some data compression theory...). But this approach has many advantages since it is easier to identify patterns using only bitwise operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ilent2 notes, the approach you're currently using won't actually work, because the symbol representations you're using aren't bitwise separable (e.g, `A = 1`, `B = 2`, and `C = 3` break because `A | B = C`).

The straightforward way to fix this would be to use five bits per position, and use:

```
A = 0x01 (0b00001)
B = 0x02 (0b00010)
C = 0x04 (0b00100)
D = 0x08 (0b01000)
E = 0x10 (0b10000)
F = 0x1F (0b11111)
```

However, there's a clever way to do this by representing each symbol as two bits set in a four-bit field, because there are 6 (`= 4 x 3 ÷ 2`) possible combinations:

```
A = 0x3 (0b0011)
B = 0x5 (0b0101)
C = 0x9 (0b1001)
D = 0x6 (0b0110)
E = 0xA (0b1010)
    0xC (0b1100) - unused, but available for one more symbol
F = 0xF (0b1111)
```

This way, the bitwise AND or OR of any two symbols is never another valid symbol.

As far as detecting matches goes, the approach you're already using is on the right track. Make use of bit shifting to detect matches in multiple locations, rather than having a separate pattern for each combination.

Comment: Using either of the two tables in your answer, how would one represent five-code combinations that include adjacent duplicates, like "AAABC", "AAFBB", etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my fairly fast code.

It takes as input an array of 5 chars (example: `"AAFBB"`), and tracks how many consecutive letters it finds.  Anytime the consecutive count is 3 or greater, it increments a `Win` counter for that letter.

It finally returns an array of 5 integers, indicating the wins for each one.
So for input `"AAFBB"`, the output is  `{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}` indicating that A and B both "won" once.

(the caller is responsible for freeing the array returned)

```
int* checkWins(char input[5])
{
    int  Counts[5]= {0};
    int* Wins = (int*)calloc(5, sizeof(int));

    char prevSymbol=input[0];

    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        if (input[i] == 'F')
        {
            // WildCard!  Increment ALL counters
            for(int j=0; j<5; ++j)
            {
                Counts[j]++;
                if (Counts[j] >= 3)
                {
                    Wins[j]++;
                }
            }
            prevSymbol = input[i];
            continue;
        }

        if (input[i] == prevSymbol || prevSymbol == 'F')
        {
            Counts[ input[i]-'A']++;
            if (Counts[ input[i]-'A'] >= 3)
            {
                Wins[ input[i]-'A']++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Counts[prevSymbol-'A']=0;
        }
        prevSymbol = input[i];
    }
    return Wins;
}

int main(void)
{
    int* wins = checkWins("AAFBB");

    // Check wins[0]... wins[4] for winners.
    // wins[0] and wins[1] should both be 1
    // Indicating AAA and BBB according to the rules.

    free(wins );
}
```

Comment: +1 This makes it very convenient to differentiate A-win from B-win.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to determine the results in a single pass through the string of symbols.  This code does that:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* You can have 0, 1 or 2 wins */

typedef struct WinInfo
{
    unsigned char streak;
    unsigned char letter;
    unsigned char start;
} WinInfo;
typedef struct Win
{
    int wins;
    WinInfo windata[2];
} Win;

static void add_win(Win *win, int streak, int start, char letter)
{
    assert(win->wins >= 0 && win->wins <= 1);
    win->windata[win->wins].streak = streak;
    win->windata[win->wins].letter = letter;
    win->windata[win->wins].start = start;
    win->wins++;
}

static void print_win(Win *win, const char symbol[5])
{
    assert(win->wins >= 0 && win->wins <= 2);
    if (win->wins == 0)
        printf("No win for [%.5s]\n", symbol);
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < win->wins; i++)
        {
            printf("Win %d: %d-%c starting at %d in [%.5s]\n",
                   i, win->windata[i].streak, win->windata[i].letter,
                   win->windata[i].start, symbol);
        }
    }
}

static Win check_win(const char symbol[5])
{
    int streak = 0;
    int start = -1;
    char letter = 0;
    Win result = { 0 };

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (symbol[i] == 'F' || symbol[i-1] == 'F' || symbol[i] == symbol[i-1])
        {
            /* Current and prior symbols are the same, or at least one is 'F' */
            if (start == -1)
            {
                streak = 2;
                start  = i-1;
                letter = symbol[i];
                if (letter == 'F')
                    letter = symbol[i-1];
            }
            else if (symbol[i] != 'F' && letter != 'F' && symbol[i] != letter)
            {
                /* End of a streak -- for example: AFB, FAFB, AAB, FFAB, AFFB */
                if (streak >= 3)
                    add_win(&result, streak, start, letter);
                /* Reset start ... */
                if (symbol[i-1] != 'F')
                {
                    streak = 0;
                    start = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    /* Step back to first 'F' not preceded by another 'F' */
                    int j = i;
                    while (symbol[j-1] == 'F')
                        j--;
                    start = j;
                    streak = i - j + 1;
                    letter = symbol[i];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (letter == 'F')
                    letter = symbol[i];
                streak++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* Mismatch between current and prior symbol */
            if (streak >= 3)
                add_win(&result, streak, start, letter);
            streak = 0;
            start = -1;
        }
    }
    if (streak >= 3)
        add_win(&result, streak, start, letter);
    return result;
}

#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const struct test
    {
        char *symbols;
        Win   win;
    } tests[] =
    {
        /* W2WB - wall-to-wall braces */
        { "AAAAA", { 1, { { 5, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "AAAAB", { 1, { { 4, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "AAABB", { 1, { { 3, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "AAABC", { 1, { { 3, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "AABBC", { 0, { { 0,   0, 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "AAFBB", { 2, { { 3, 'A', 0 }, { 3, 'B', 2 } } } },
        { "AAFBC", { 1, { { 3, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "AAFFB", { 2, { { 4, 'A', 0 }, { 3, 'B', 2 } } } },
        { "ABCDE", { 0, { { 0,   0, 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "ABCDF", { 0, { { 0,   0, 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "ABCFE", { 0, { { 0,   0, 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "AFABB", { 1, { { 3, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "AFFFB", { 2, { { 4, 'A', 0 }, { 4, 'B', 1 } } } },
        { "AFAFA", { 1, { { 5, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "AFAFB", { 1, { { 4, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "AFFFF", { 1, { { 5, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "BAAAA", { 1, { { 4, 'A', 1 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "BAAAC", { 1, { { 3, 'A', 1 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "BCAAA", { 1, { { 3, 'A', 2 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "FAABB", { 1, { { 3, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "FFAAB", { 1, { { 4, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "FFABB", { 1, { { 3, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "FFFAB", { 1, { { 4, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "FFFBB", { 1, { { 5, 'B', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "FFFFA", { 1, { { 5, 'A', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
        { "FFFFF", { 1, { { 5, 'F', 0 }, { 0,   0, 0 } } } },
    };
    enum { NUM_TESTS = sizeof(tests)/sizeof(tests[0]) };

    int pass = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++)
    {
        Win result = check_win(tests[i].symbols);
        print_win(&result, tests[i].symbols);
        if (result.wins == tests[i].win.wins)
        {
            int fail = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < result.wins; n++)
            {
                /* Update to record/verify start too */
                if (result.windata[n].streak != tests[i].win.windata[n].streak ||
                    result.windata[n].letter != tests[i].win.windata[n].letter ||
                    result.windata[n].start  != tests[i].win.windata[n].start)
                {
                    printf("!! FAIL !! (wanted %d-%c @%d, actual %d-%c @%d)\n",
                           tests[i].win.windata[n].streak, tests[i].win.windata[n].letter,
                           tests[i].win.windata[n].start, result.windata[n].streak,
                           result.windata[n].letter, result.windata[n].start);
                    fail++;
                }
            }
            if (fail == 0)
                pass++;
        }
        else
            printf("!! FAIL !! (%s: wanted %d, actual %d)\n",
                   tests[i].symbols, tests[i].win.wins, result.wins);
    }
    if (pass == NUM_TESTS)
        printf("== PASS ==\n");
    else
        printf("!! FAIL !! (%d pass, %d fail)\n", pass, NUM_TESTS-pass);

    printf("\nRandom play:\n");
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char symbols[5];
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            symbols[j] = rand() % 6 + 'A';
        }
        Win result = check_win(symbols);
        print_win(&result, symbols);
    }

    return (pass != NUM_TESTS); /* 0 success, 1 failure */
}
```

It has a stringent test phase that ensures it produces correct results on specially chosen test cases.  It also has a 'random play' section that tries the game at random.

Example output:

```
Win 0: 5-A starting at 0 in [AAAAA]
Win 0: 4-A starting at 0 in [AAAAB]
Win 0: 3-A starting at 0 in [AAABB]
Win 0: 3-A starting at 0 in [AAABC]
No win for [AABBC]
Win 0: 3-A starting at 0 in [AAFBB]
Win 1: 3-B starting at 2 in [AAFBB]
Win 0: 3-A starting at 0 in [AAFBC]
Win 0: 4-A starting at 0 in [AAFFB]
Win 1: 3-B starting at 2 in [AAFFB]
No win for [ABCDE]
No win for [ABCDF]
No win for [ABCFE]
Win 0: 3-A starting at 0 in [AFABB]
Win 0: 4-A starting at 0 in [AFFFB]
Win 1: 4-B starting at 1 in [AFFFB]
Win 0: 5-A starting at 0 in [AFAFA]
Win 0: 4-A starting at 0 in [AFAFB]
Win 0: 5-A starting at 0 in [AFFFF]
Win 0: 4-A starting at 1 in [BAAAA]
Win 0: 3-A starting at 1 in [BAAAC]
Win 0: 3-A starting at 2 in [BCAAA]
Win 0: 3-A starting at 0 in [FAABB]
Win 0: 4-A starting at 0 in [FFAAB]
Win 0: 3-A starting at 0 in [FFABB]
Win 0: 4-A starting at 0 in [FFFAB]
Win 0: 5-B starting at 0 in [FFFBB]
Win 0: 5-A starting at 0 in [FFFFA]
Win 0: 5-F starting at 0 in [FFFFF]
== PASS ==

Random play:
Win 0: 3-B starting at 1 in [DBBBA]
No win for [DEECC]
No win for [ACAED]
Win 0: 4-D starting at 0 in [DFFFA]
Win 1: 4-A starting at 1 in [DFFFA]
No win for [FADFA]
No win for [CAEAF]
Win 0: 3-C starting at 2 in [AECFF]
No win for [EDAED]
No win for [EDEAC]
Win 0: 3-C starting at 1 in [EFCCA]
```

This revision of the code loses the static variables that caused problems mentioned in the comments.  It also separates the reporting structure from the printing of the results.  The `check_win()` function doesn't print anything; that's now the job for `print_win()`.  The changes were not huge, really (but they'll look huge if you diff the files because of name changes and structure changes.

Comment: Hi , you method is very nice , I will try to use this method, however, you forgot to reset golbal value `wins` to `0`, which cause a segment fault . :)

Comment: Ugh!  Thanks.  Globals are nasty...I really need to work out how to get rid of that one, or make it autosynchronizing, or ... It was used to get an accurate report on the matches that were found.  I need to choose a better way to do it.  Maybe the `check_win()` function shoudl return a structure containing a count of wins plus the encoded wins array.  There can never be more than two wins with the rules you set up.

Comment: It's ok,it is fast ,and simple logic, could I use this in my work ?

Comment: You can use this code if you want.  I've updated it to remove the globals, which prevents there being a problem with not resetting a global...  The changes look big if you diff this version with the previous version, but the changes are really rather small.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are putting the symbols in an array of integers where each integer from 0 to 6 corresponds to your symbols where 1 = A and F = 6. Then you just loop over the given input and for each symbol check the following x to see if you see a triplet of 3. The outer loop will run 6 times and the inner loop will run 6 - i times at most. This will print out duplicates (would print a 4A win and 3A win for input AAAABE) but you can fix that.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        int candidate = symbols[i];
        int j = i;

        while (candidate == symbols[j] || symbols[i] == 6 && j < 6)
        {
            j++;
        }

        if (j - i >= 3)
        {
            // win of type candidate with length of j - i
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the values as follows: A = 10 , B = 100, C = 1000, D = 10000, E = 100000, F = 1. I think `enum` can help you with that.
Then you just add the values of your output string to let's say `sum`. So `fNumber = sum % 10` is the number of your `F`'s, `aNumber = sum % 10`  and so on. Then just check whether `aNumber + fNumber >= 3`.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your suggested masks. Moreover, you do not need to detect the game result at all:

Theoretically, every five-letter win has a 1/7776 probability of occurring; every three-letter win, a 105/7776 chance. If you set your random generator to output a number between 1 and 7776, and correlate each mask with one of those numbers (or a range in the case of the three-letter win), the program will know "in advance" whether there is a win or not, and of which kind.

If there is no win, show a random no-win shuffle.